# Relative and Absolute Path In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, relative-path, absolute-path

I have the following very simple code which just reads a JSON file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSON Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
    alert (1);
    $.getJSON('data/sample.json', function(json) 
    {
        alert(2);

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="datadiv">This is the info:  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I load the above file on a Tomcat server and can load the file using:  `http://myserver.com:8080/Html5_Test_1/jsonTest.html`. The above code works, and alert(2) is called.  However, if I change the path that that I use for getJSON to /Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json, it won't work.

I think that /Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json is the absolute path for data/sample.json, and should work.  In fact I've tried /data/sample.json, Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json, and none works.  The only path that works is data/sample.json.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?  The absolute path /Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json would certainly work in Java.  So, is the concept of absolute and relative path a bit different in JavaScript?

Note that the file is being accessed as public file on the server and not as a file on the local file system.

Comment: Have you confirmed by typing the address directly on the browser's URL bar (http://localhost:8080/Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json)? If you look in the network tab of the browser's dev tools, what URL does it try to load?

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that the file can be loaded using localhost:8080/Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json.

Comment: Ok, can you check the actual content of `GET` request when you specify `'/Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json'` as URL? And compare this line with the one sent by `'data/sample.json'` request.

Comment: Yes, the headers say that the file being requested is http://myserver.com:8080/Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json which is the correct path; but the script still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to mix absolute/relative filesystem paths and absolute/relative URLs. Remember, JavaScript is *client-side* language, it has nothing to do with the filesystem of the server that hosts its master page. So you'd rather put up a relative URL, taking into account that it's starting point will most probably be the path of the served file.

But why it works now, you may ask? Check this:

```
/Html5_Test_1/
.. data/
.... sample.json
.. jsonTest.html
```

... and remember, an URL will be taken as related to the directory which contains *jsonTest.html* file. It's easy to see why proper relative path is `data/sample.json` (or `'./data/sample.json'`).

If you wish, you can change your code to something like this...

```
$.getJSON('file:///Html5_Test_1/data/sample.json', function(json) ...);
```

... but this obviously will make it unusable on any other machine than yours.

Comment: I don't think you can load files from the local file system with AJAX even on your own computer.

Comment: Although the server is obviously on the local host, but the file sample.json is being accessed as a file on the server, and not as a file on the local file system.

Comment: @Juhana Yes, even that's restricted in some browsers (Chrome). These restrictions may be lifted, but that's not the point: I've tried to show the difference between filesystem paths and URLs.